# my javascript say 'undefined' in variable when choosing element trough window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have an element with Id of

```
#accordion-tab-1
```

which I try to call with

```
$(`${window.location.hash}`).prop(`hash`)
```

and I get 'undefined' when I console.log it but when I do only

```
$(`${window.location.hash}`)
```

I get element with that Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your URL contains `#accordion-tab-1` than all you need to do to select is use direct hash:

```
$(window.location.hash)
```

Also use normal quotes `'` instead of `. More: selecting element and than doing`.prop('hash')`leads to`undefined`as DOM element does not have property named`hash`

Comment: hmmm why then this console.log($('#02-desktop-accordion-label').prop('hash')); I get hash from href

Comment: @OunknownO You did not provide DOM structure. Maybe `#accordion-tab-1` is not `<a>` and `#02-desktop-accordion-label` is? Or first link does not have hash in URL?

Comment: I did this on click on element i just did this 'this.hash' and I get the hash of link